# Function for Autocorrelation

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Is there a built in function to compute the [autocorrelation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) of a signal ?

Comment: You can get ListCorrelate to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the help file for `ListConvolve`, to find the autocorrelation of a list:

```
data = Table[Mod[i^2, 17], {i, 100}];
autocorrelation = ListConvolve[data, data, {1, 1}];
ListLinePlot[autocorrelation ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This only works because the list in the example is circularly even. `(# == Reverse[#]) &@Rest@Table[Mod[i^2, 17], {i, 100}]` gives `True`

Answer (score 16):

Yes, in version 9 you have [`CorrelationFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CorrelationFunction.html) built in.

```
data = Table[Mod[i^2, 17], {i, 100}];
autocorrelation = CorrelationFunction[data, {0, Length[data] - 1}];

ListLinePlot[autocorrelation]
```

[image: autocorrelation]

Comment: @OleksandrR Thanks, I missed this in the documentation! (It's also ~100 faster :)

Comment: This does not seem to match the output of the ListConvolve method (just look at the y-scale).  Using some test functions like a square pulse and a triangular pulse, I also don't get the expected output using CorrelationFunction.  Any idea what the discrepancy is?  I'm working with some applications of autocorrelation functions and I'm struggling to find the discrepancy between the two methods.

Comment: @skratch Nope. Look under the help to see exactly what is calculated using CorrelationFunction.

Comment: In response to myself and anyone else who may be interested:
The "CorrelationFunction" approach seems to indeed be the "correct" one if you're looking for an autocorrelation function (ACF).  I'm not so sure about ListConvolve and ListCorrelate...  In v9, CorrelationFunction is scaled to vary between 1 and -1 and takes its maximum value at the first data point, which is a property of autocorrelation functions.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this satisfies you?

`autocorrelate[exp_, varFrom_, varTo_]:=Convolve[exp, exp/.varFrom->-varFrom, varFrom, varTo]`

If your signal is discrete but symbolic, change `Convolve` to `DiscreteConvolve`. If they are lists, check out `ListCorrelate`

Answer (score 1):

If you search the docs for "autocorrelation", `ListConvolve` turns up. There's also `ListCorrelate`. Does this work for you?

Comment: @Rojo the point I was sort of making is that typing "autocorrelate" in the help viewer takes you to `ListConvolve` which has an example.